# inheritance in php

Tags: php, inheritance

I build those classes:

```
class Anonym
{
    public $ToSelect;
    public $ToUpdate;
    public $ToInsert;
    public $ToDelete;
    public $limit;
    public $order_by;
    public $filter;

    public function is_banned($ipAddress)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM anonym WHERE ip='$ipAddress'";
    }

   public function insert_ip()
   {
            $serverAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $query="INSERT INTO anonym (ip,banned) 
                VALUES('$serverAddress',0)";
   }

    public function update_ban($update_ban)
    {
            $serverAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $query="UPDATE anonym SET ban=$update_ban WHERE ip='$serverAddress'";
    }

}

class User extends Anonym
{

    public function get_user_id()
    {
        $select="SELECT ".$ToSelect." FROM users ".$filter.$order_by.$limit;
    }

    public function insert_user()
    {
        $select="INSERT INTO users (name, password,roles) VALUES (".$ToInsert.")";
    }

    public function get_user_name()
    {
        $select="SELECT ".$ToSelect." FROM users ".$filter.$order_by.$limit;
    }

    public function get_user_role()
    {
        $select="SELECT ".$ToSelect." FROM users ".$filter.$order_by.$limit;
    } 
}
```

The anonym user is inherited by the logged in user. What I am not sure about is how to inherit those properties,.. Is this the right way to do so? or do I need to add $this-> , so that the overriding will occur.

Also, is method overriding is simple in php?!?

so if I do this:

```
$user=new User();
$user->insert_ip(); // will the overriding be successful or do I need to use some special syntax?
```

Answer (score -1):

- Yes is that simple.
- Yes it will do override.

I hope you know making variable `$query` is not enough.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM anonym WHERE ip='$ipAddress'";
mysql_query($query); // !!!
```

As far i know inheritance is that simple in other languages as well...

Comment: I could return it, and iterate over the results..I know

Comment: cause I made a mistake that you didnt notice. to override you need to do this on property:$this->filter not $filter

Comment: * Yes is that simple. <--- why did you put that statemnt..and not commented on  this ::::$this->filter didnt you notice the error I made. Properties get inherited like methods do.. when I apply a method or property of the subclass, it is getting overriden and not inherited

Comment: You ask about overriding and i put answer about overriding. I've just ask about $query to make sure you know what are you doing.